# Transform rows to columns(probably pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my requirement:

```
create table #TEMP
(
KEY_VALUE VARCHAR(100)
,NAME VARCHAR(100)
,AMOUNT INT
,QUANTITY INT
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES
('K1','ABC',100,10000),
('K2','XYZ',200,20000),
('K1','ABC',50,5000),
('K2','XYZ',300,30000),
('K3','MNO',50,500)

select * from #TEMP
```

[image]

Because the KEY_VALUE COLUMN matches for 2 rows(K1 and K2), I want to transform it to something as below:

```
KEY_VALUE   NAME    AMOUNT_1 AMOUNT_2   QUANTITY_1 QUANTITY_2
K1          ABC     100      50         10000      5000
K2          XYZ     200      300        20000      30000
K3          MNO     50       NULL       500        NULL
```

What/How do I do that? Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? Is 2 the maximum one to many relationship? Could there be 3, 4, 100?

Comment: Is 2 the maximum one to many relationship? - Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` & do conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT KEY_VALUE, NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 1 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 2 THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 1 THEN QUANTITY END) AS QUANTITY_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 2 THEN QUANTITY END) AS QUANTITY_2
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KEY_VALUE ORDER BY AMOUNT) AS seq
      FROM #TEMP t
     ) t
GROUP BY KEY_VALUE, NAME;
```

**EDIT** : If you want to do further calculation then you can use `CTE` :

```
WITH CTE AS (
     <query>
)
SELECT C.*, 
       C.AMOUNT_1 - C.AMOUNT_1 AS Diff_Amt
FROM CTE C;
```

Comment: I agree on this .. but I dont want to use group by as I have follow up calculations like difference between amount1 and amount_2 to be shown as third column. Using group by will lead me to write unnecessary aggregate functions.

Comment: How will the performance be? CTE with a derived table and then a row_number. My data volume is somewhere 3million.

Comment: @Ayush. . Performance would be concern more about table structure i.e. index design.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare data

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
    key_value varchar(10),
    name varchar(10),
    amount int,
    quantity int
);

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES 
('K1', 'ABC', 100, 10000),
('K2', 'XYZ', 200, 20000),
('K1', 'ABC', 50, 5000),
('K2', 'XYZ', 300, 30000),
('K3', 'MNO', 50, 500);
```

Querying

```
WITH t1 (id, key_value, name, amount, quantity)
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY key_value), key_value, name, amount, quantity FROM #t
),
t2
AS (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id, MAX(id) AS max_id, key_value, name 
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY key_value, name
),
t3
AS (
    SELECT t2.key_value, t2.name, 
        t11.amount AS amount_1, t11.quantity AS quantity_1,
        t12.amount AS amount_2, t12.quantity AS quantity_2
    FROM t2 
        INNER JOIN 
        t1 t11 ON t11.key_value = t2.key_value AND t11.name = t2.name 
            AND t11.id = t2.min_id
        LEFT JOIN
        t1 t12 ON t12.key_value = t2.key_value AND t12.name = t2.name 
            AND t12.id = t2.max_id AND t12.id <> t2.min_id
)
SELECT * FROM t3
```

Result

```
key_value  name       amount_1    quantity_1  amount_2    quantity_2
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
K1         ABC        100         10000       50          5000
K2         XYZ        300         30000       200         20000
K3         MNO        50          500         NULL        NULL
```